# How to use BeautifulSoup to get parent tag's name value when the parent tag's children has certain attribute values?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, attributes, tags

To make this question easier to understand, below is an example

```
<Tag name="Thumbnail" inline="no" nonsearchable="yes">
<Attribute>
<Attribute name="AText" Searchable="yes"></Attribute>
</Attribute>
</Tag>

<Tag name="Label" inline="no" nonsearchable="yes">
<Attribute>
<Attribute name="AText" Searchable="no"></Attribute>
</Attribute>
</Tag>

<Tag name="Image" inline="no" nonsearchable="yes">
<Attribute>
<Attribute name="BText" Searchable="yes">
</Attribute>
</Tag>

<Tag name="Wonder" inline="no" nonsearchable="yes">
<Attribute>
<Attribute name="BText" Searchable="yes"></Attribute>
</Attribute>
</Tag>
```

**Expected Result**

[image]

So in the excel, the first row should be the the **Attribute** tag's *name value* if the **Attribute** tag's **Searchable** value is "**yes**"; Then these "qualified" **Attributes** tag's parent tag - **Tag** - *name value* would be listed underneath.

Currently, I can only find all the **Tag**'s name value if it's children's Searchable value is "yes", but can't categorize them under corresponding **Attribute** tag's name value. Below is my initial code:

```
import os, openpyxl
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

cwd = os.getcwd()

def func(x):
    for file in os.listdir(cwd):
        if file.endswith('.xml'):
            f = open(file, encoding = 'utf=8', mode = 'r+')
            soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'lxml')
            AttrYES = soup.find_all(attrs={"Searchable": "yes"})
            for items in AttrYES:
                tagName = items.parent.parent.get('name')
                print (tagName)

x = os.listdir(cwd)
func(x)
```

I'll try to work this out as well, but to make the process faster, if you have any ideas, please advice. Thank you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code cannot find anything, if you print `AttrYES`, it will be `[]` . The thing is that when you use `bs4` with parser `lxml`, all tag and attr name will convert to lowercase,refer to [official doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#other-parser-problems). If you print the soup, it will give you:

```
<html><body><tag inline="no" name="Thumbnail" nonsearchable="yes">
<attribute>
<attribute name="AText" searchable="yes"></attribute>
</attribute>
</tag>
<tag inline="no" name="Label" nonsearchable="yes">
<attribute>
<attribute name="AText" searchable="no"></attribute>
</attribute>
</tag>
<tag inline="no" name="Image" nonsearchable="yes">
<attribute>
<attribute name="BText" searchable="yes">
</attribute>
</attribute></tag>
<tag inline="no" name="Wonder" nonsearchable="yes">
<attribute>
<attribute name="BText" searchable="yes"></attribute>
</attribute>
</tag></body></html>
```

Hence, you could amend your code like this:

```
import bs4
f = open('test.xml',mode = 'r+')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(f, 'lxml')
AttrYES = soup.findAll(attrs={'searchable': 'yes'})
result = dict()
for items in AttrYES:
    result[items.get('name')] = result.get(items.get('name'),[])+[items.parent.parent.get('name')]    
print(result)
```

The print will be :

```
{'AText': ['Thumbnail'], 'BText': ['Image', 'Wonder']}
```

Then you could write them to your excel file:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('result.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Write header
worksheet.write(0, 0, result.keys()[0])
worksheet.write(0, 1, result.keys()[1])

# Write data.
worksheet.write_column(1, 0, result.values()[0])
worksheet.write_column(1, 1, result.values()[1])

workbook.close()
```

The `result.xlsx` will be:

[image]

**Update:** with openpyxl

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()

# grab the active worksheet
ws = wb.active

# Data can be assigned directly to cells
i,j = 1,1
for keys,values in a.items():
    ws.cell(column=i, row=1, value=keys)
    for row in range(len(values)):
        ws.cell(column=i, row=j+1, value=values[row])
        j+=1
    j=1
    i+=1
wb.save("result.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution Tiny1

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution Tiny! Yes, I can get the result printed like this `{'AText': ['Thumbnail'], 'BText': ['Image', 'Wonder']}`. This is great! Right now I'm trying to use python's built-in module openpyxl though. Some issues come up: First of all, python3 doesn't allow `result.values()` to have index anymore; secondly, if we don't know how many keys there are, we probably need to write a loop for the values. I think it's easier to loop the keys, but for the values, I'm still trying figure out how. If you have any ideas, that'd be wonderful! Thank you! :)

Comment: Most recent update: I can loop the key onto the correct excel cells by writing `for key in result.keys():`    
    `sheetOut.cell(row=1, column=r).value = key`    
    `r+=1`    
`n = 1`    However, if I loop value the same way, the cell content would be ['Thumbnail'] and ['Image', 'Wonder'] . So Still trying to figure this out.

Comment: Please check the updated answer: 1, you can use function items() in python3; 2, use for loop, check the updated answer.

Comment: 1, you can for loop and function items() in python3 to get the keys and values of dictionary; 2, for loop the items first, then in the values, another for loop the values list to get the every element, in the first for loop, write key in the first row, the second for loop, write the values into same column but next row. Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: You are the best Tiny! the script works like a charm. :)